# Why is LocalStorage element listed at two levels of Azure service definition schema?

Tags: windows, deployment, azure, cloud, local-storage

According to [Azure service definition schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg557553.aspx) `LocalStorage` element can be present either in `<WebRole><LocalResources>` (this location is used in samples found everywhere) or right in `<WebRole>` itself (which is not used in samples).

Why is it listed on two different levels of the XML schema? What happens if I define a local storage in each level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably just backward compatibility. (The location presumably changed and we kept the old syntax as an option so existing service definition files could still work.)

Comment: In early Azure version you defined it under WebRole. In later versions this was changed so that you can define multiple LocalStorage elements under LocalResources. The old method still works (although it is limited to the single LocalStorage definition).